# How to make comparisons using "like" in japanese?

Tags: word-choice, set-phrases

So take the following (contrived) example in english.

> A: What does 'plane' mean?
>   B: Which 'plane'? 'Plane' like 'the thing in the sky'? 'Plain' like 'hills on the ground'? Or 'plane' like 'a pocket dimension'?

Another example in Japanese:

> A: 「なのか」はどういう意味ですか？
>   B: どっちの「なのか」？「なのか」 **like** 「みっか」？「なのか」 **like** 「だよね」?

How do I express the 'like' in that way in Japanese?

Comment: Don't these two nanoka differ in accent?

Answer (score 6):

Informally, I would suggest 「みたいな」 or even just 「の」.  One can say:

> 「みっか、よっか」みたいな「なのか」？
>
> 「みっか、よっか」の「なのか」？

Answer (score 6):

In casual speech, you might say:

> A: 「なのか」ってどういう意味？
>   B: どっちの「なのか」？「なのか、ようか」（とか（言うとき））の「なのか」？（それとも、）「なのですか」って意味の「なのか」？

If you want to sound politer you might say:

> A: 「なのか」はどういう意味ですか？
>   B: どっち（orどちら）の「なのか」ですか？「なのか、ようか」（など）の「なのか」ですか、それとも「なのですか」という意味の「なのか」ですか？